# Documentation for Adobe PDF Reader control axAcroPDF

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-framework-version, axacropdf

Where can I find a list of public parameters and methods for axAcroPDF control? I'm most interested in string parameters list for setView() method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you haven't found it already, the documentation for axAcroPDF can be found in [this document](https://web.archive.org/web/20170829005542/http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_api_reference.pdf) .